# require to change the dropdown item for other row's dropdown item in wpf

Tags: wpf

i have a list view with the following code

```
<ListView Name="configurationModeGrid" Width="400" Margin="236,440,58,143" BorderBrush="Black" FontFamily="Microsoft Sans Serif" FontSize="11">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="Network">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Name="NetworkName" Height="20" Width="108" Text="{Binding NetworkName, Mode=OneWay}"  Background="#FFFFCAA6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource DisableText}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="110" Header="Trend Mode">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Name="TrendListItems" Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="108" ItemsSource="{Binding TrendModeList}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentMode}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxCombo}" SelectionChanged="TrendListItems_SelectionChanged" >

                                </ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>

                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="LAN" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="LanNumber"  Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="48" Text="{Binding LanNumber,Mode=OneWay}" IsEnabled="False" Background="#FFFFCAA6"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource DisableText}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Label" Width="100">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Name="LanLabel" Margin="-5,0,-5,0" Width="98" Text="{Binding LanLabel, Mode=OneWay}" Background="#FFFFCAA6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

1. The dropdown list will bind the following options

   i) internetwork
   II) lan
   iii) none

Question

1. if the lan item in dropdownlist is selected from the row one of list view, i would like to make other other dropdownlist item's item must become none.

Can this be done using WPF UI or have to use only data model for this?

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. what you mean by other dropdownlist item ?

Comment: when i ment by other dropdownlist item, i mean the dropdownlist of subsequent rows. e.g. when i select an item from row one dropdownlist, i want to change the second rows dropdownlist item.